# JavaFX Using Netbeans Template Javfx FML Application

Tags: netbeans, javafx, fxmlloader

I thing it is a very silly question but I don't manage to to this. If you made a FXML-Template Project with Java, you got automatically three files. The view in XML, the controller and the start file in java. 
I want to use the scene in the controller class but I don't know how to make a reference to do this. 
Here is my example:

```
public class CatchTheScene extends Application {
private Scene scene;
private Parent root;



@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    FXMLDocumentController controller = new FXMLDocumentController(this);
    scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

/**
 * @return the scene
 */
public Scene getScene() {
    return scene;
}

/**
 * @param scene the scene to set
 */
public void setScene(Scene scene) {
    this.scene = scene;
}
```

}

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

```
private CatchTheScene c; 
@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private Button button;
@FXML
private AnchorPane root;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    label.setText("Hello World!");
}

public FXMLDocumentController(CatchTheScene c)
{
    this.c = c; 
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    c.getScene().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
           System.out.println("I am the scene and have been clicked");
        }
   });
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do this in the controller? The `Scene` is not part of the FXML, so it doesn't really make a lot of sense to register event handlers on it in the FXML's controller. You can register a handler with the scene in the `Application.start()` method, or (probably less common) create the `Scene` in the FXML file.

Comment: The example above is just an example to simplify my problem. I try to make  a game where I want to put all the controlling in the controllers class according to the  MVC pattern.  So it would be perfect if you know how to handle the problem. I made the GUI thing with the Scene Builder. Maybe there is a possibility to declare the Scene in the Scene Builder. In  this case it would be no problem to handle my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now. First I gave in the Scene Builder a Code FX:ID named root to the root pane.
root is in the controller an object and I registered on root an EventListener.`

```
@FXML
private Canvas canvas;
@FXML
private AnchorPane root;

root.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {

                clownfish.setDx(-10);
                clownfish.moveLeft();
            }
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {

                clownfish.setDx(-10);
                clownfish.moveRight();
            }

            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {

                clownfish.setDy(-10);
                clownfish.moveUp();
            }
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {

                clownfish.setDy(-10);
                clownfish.moveDown();
            }
        }
    });
```